# Parse And Paypal Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, parse-platform, linker

I'm trying to add PayPal into my iOS application that uses Parse.
After following the official PayPal guide on GitHub I'm getting this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)   "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
>         -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in
>   Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>         -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add Framework Social.framework  and Accounts.framework from project settings.

Please check parse.com integration  [Help Links](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/native/existing)